# Why does the Run as Spring Boot App keyboard shortcut not work in Spring Tools Suite

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

So in my Spring Boot Project as loaded in Spring Tools Suite Version: 3.9.4.RELEASE.I can never get the noted keyboard shortcut to run the open project.

I always have to right click on the project directory go down to Run As, and then select "Spring Boot App"

[image: Windows Spring Tools Suite Run As Menu for Spring Boot Project]
 [image: Mac OS - Spring Tools Suite Run As Menu for Spring Boot Project]

As noted in the drop down there is a key board shortcut of <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd> Which I interpret to mean hold down the fist 3 keys listed and then press B. Either way the shortcut never does anything, and I have to use the mouse to start projects, what am I doing wrong here?

Updated how about the Mac version?

It looks like <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

Comment: It seems to work for me. I clicked the project to select it in the package explorer window. Then press ALT-SHIFT-X, pause a short while releasing all keys, then hit 'B' and app launches.

Comment: That works for me, thanks. Looks like an answer to me..

Comment: Space means pause on mac (spaceforce), was not working on my Mac because STS had issues starting and stopping initially from running too long, either way force quit STS and the mac short cut now works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I do and it works for me:

- click the project to select it in the package explorer window.
- Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>
- Pause a short while releasing all keys
- Hit <kbd>B</kbd>

=> app launches

Comment: Ya that release keys and pause is the key to it, is that what a "," means in a short cut listing... Very odd... but it works for me now, thanks...

Comment: Yes, I think keyboard shortcuts are bound to a series of 'keystrokes' separated by a ','. A keystroke is a combination of keys pressed together. To move on to the next keystroke you have to release the keys you pressed so you can then hit another set of keys. So the 'comma' means 'release keys' :-)

Comment: It Works for me, thanks

Spring Tool Suite 3
Version: 3.9.10.RELEASE
Build Id: 201909190739
Java version: 1.8.0_66